# What's the difference between return true and return false in OnInit() function of MFC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

In the source code generated by the template for a Dialog based MFC application the `InitInstance()` of the main application, derived from `CWinApp`, initializes the application environment and then creates the dialog that is the main application interface and displays it with `DoModal()`. When the displayed dialog returns, the application finishes and terminates.

In the main application interface dialog that is derived from `CDialogEx` there is a method `OnInitDialog()` which is called as part of initializing the dialog.

What is the difference between returning `TRUE` or returning `FALSE` from this method?

```
BOOL CMyTabDlgs::OnInitDialog() 
{ 
    CDialog::OnInitDialog() ;
    // Some code
    return true;
}
```

and

```
BOOL CMyTabDlgs::OnInitDialog() 
{ 
    CDialog::OnInitDialog() ;
    // Some code
    return false;
}
```

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/fwz35s59(v=vs.60)

Comment: What does [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdialog-class#oninitdialog) tell you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `OnInitDialog()` member function is called by the MFC framework when it is processing a `WM_INITDIALOG` message.

The purpose of this member function is to provide a place to perform any special initialization of the dialog's controls and interface.

One of the events that can be done in the `OnInitDialog()` method is to set the focus to one of the controls in the dialog. This action allows the programmer to decide which control (button, edit window, combo box, etc.) displayed in the dialog should have the focus first.

Or the programmer can just allow the MFC framework to make that decision for them.

If the programmer sets the focus to a particular control, the `OnInitDialog()` method should return `FALSE` so that the MFC Runtime knows that the focus has already been set.

If the programmer does not set the focus to a particular control, the `OnInitDialog()` method should return `TRUE` so that the MFC Runtime knows that it needs to set the focus.

That is what the comments in the `OnInitDialog()` method skeleton created by the MFC template indicate as in the code sample from https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/fwz35s59(v=vs.60)

```
BOOL CSimpleDlg::OnInitDialog() 
{ 
   CDialog::OnInitDialog(); 

   // TODO: Add extra initialization here 
   m_cMyEdit.SetWindowText(_T("My Name")); // Initialize control values 
   m_cMyList.ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);      // Show or hide a control, etc. 

   return TRUE;  // return TRUE unless you set the focus to a control 
   // EXCEPTION: OCX Property Pages should return FALSE 
}
```

The [MSDN article CPropertySheet::OnInitDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0bw65cxb.aspx) has a fuller explanation for the return value:

> Specifies whether the application has set the input focus to one of
>   the controls in the property sheet. If OnInitDialog returns nonzero,
>   Windows sets the input focus to the first control in the property
>   sheet. The application can return 0 only if it has explicitly set the
>   input focus to one of the controls in the property sheet.